# Import DirectX .X into Blender

Tags: xna, directx, blender

I spent some time now to find "tools" to work and make 3D applications with. For some reason I will use XNA 4.0. This can import .X or .FBX files for models - perhaps many more, but I do not know of this yet. Both format I want to use as text-based, not binary. I found .X making less trash text so I tried to look for free, but useful tool to edit .X files. After many downloaded trash software I found Blender to be "just fine" for my needs.

My problem was that even if Blender can export to .X and even .FBX, it can not import from these formats. I was looking for plugin for this goal, but none I have found so far, and after too many "visited links" I just lost the line, so I thought I will ask around here, if anyone knows a good way to import .X into Blender...

or

- make XNA work with other formats.
- suggest a good 3d editing program, that can edit models imported from .X or .FBX (text) and can export into one of these formats.

I used search, and am not retarded - just tried of looking-and-looking.. so.. any good idea or link is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Edit: to make it clear: my goal is to have a 3d modell editor, that can be used to edit .X (or .FBX) in text format, so I can work with XNA without converting from or into anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an importer for Blender 2.67 :

**https://github.com/littleneo/directX_blender**

it currently supports x in ascii format, imports verts, faces, uv and vertices weights (multimesh support)

there's a bit of support for parenting and armatures but it's still pending/messy.

goals of the author, which is me, are to import anything from x, and supports binary format*.

[* but I need feedback, hughs, spare time, and complex testfiles to do so ;) ]

Comment: Installed Blender to check this out, but no installer for your stuff. Downloaded as ZIP, but no info, how to manually install this. My first suggestion to put some infó about this into the readme file, so non-blender-and-help-file-addicts can install and try fast and easy.

Comment: Google was my friend, so I figured that File > User preferences > Addons will do the trick, but could not figure which file to install from file, nor did Blender tell me that I "successfully intalled anything at all", so I give up for a while, I hope you can give a hand in this.

Comment: sorry I didn't check stackoverflow since ages. I just red your need about animations and your issuse about how to install/use my addon in B2.6x . would you agree to share an animated .x files so I can code ? or give me a pointer to a .x with animation ? thx

Comment: Actually I started to make an own .x importer, and had good progress. Only thing I could not manage is the animation - I got meshes, armatures all right, but had some conversion problem with animation. If you want I can share my work with you, and even tell you about the problem; but my advice is that do not even try, unless you got good math skills or know someone with it. Send me a mail if interested ;)

Comment: cant find how to answer you by mail.. Im ok with matrices, quats and python, its with spare time Im not ok. if you write an addon in Blender sure we could share, else we can at least share logics and problems about bones and mat/quat and interpolations (I suppose). btw about manual addon installation in Blender : simply unzip the folder in the blender 'addons' folder then enable it from the blender ui. then from the menu go to import > direct x. give it another try if you go blender python.
also in github I uploaded x files to validate my code if that can help.

Comment: To get the plugin working on Blender 2.79b, use a fork from this link (my [poikilos] fork enables Blender GUI installation of the zip from the GitHub repo; Most x files will not import for some reason, so we could use some help): https://github.com/poikilos/io_import_x

Comment: @Zéiksz I hope you found the answer by now. But for others, it took me so long to find the answer I though I would share.
To install an add-on in Blender 2.83:
1. Menu: Edit\Preferences...
2. Add-ons: Click Install...
3. **Select the ZIP file!**

Answer (score 0):

Use [this program](http://web.t-online.hu/karpo/) to convert .X files to a format that Blender can import, modify it and export as a .X file.

Comment: The program that you pointed out, does not recognize x file created with a utility from 2006. in fact it does not even open 3ds properly. although its web page says 698 file types are supported!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so found out that Blender 2.49 just does the trick: can import .X and export into .X too; uses text only. Newest Blender (2.57 or so) is unable to import .X - but will export into.

So when you go for using Blender download the "older versions".

Edit: you can get previous versions here:
http://download.blender.org/release/

Edit: you can find usefull info from .X file format here: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/directx/

Comment: Note: edited to correct last know good version of Blender capable for this job done. My frist idea - v2.44 - had some bugs with .X files.

Comment: Note: must join meshes in order to import a whole scene, since Blender will load only one mesh (only the first) from a multiple-mesh .x file (, BUT will export as multiple meshes (if you do not join them first)).

Comment: Note: Blender seems to be unable to import the previously self-exported animations (how LOLish), so I guess (since there is no good importer+exporter on the net) it is time for uninstall. Unmarking this as "good answer", since Blender is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution found so far is UU3D (Ultimate Unwrap 3D), downside is that it is not free, but does the trick. For more info see this:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13399/tool-for-editing-x

Edit: Blender can Import .X.. not animations tho' and only one mesh. Up to version 2.49b it can export with animations. So better to write an own plugin, because the shipped one is crap.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so found out that Blender 2.49 just does the trick: can import .X and export into .X too; uses text only. Newest Blender (2.57 or so) is unable to import .X - but will export into.

So when you go for using Blender download the "older versions".

Edit: you can get previous versions here: http://download.blender.org/release/

Edit: you can find usefull info from .X file format here: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/directx/

Answer (score -3):

You can use [Alin's DirectX Exporter for 3ds Max](http://www.cgdev.net), It supports standard and DirectX shader materials, use it to export your scene data as DirectX (.x) file, then import it into Blender.

[download it's free version](http://www.cgdev.net/download.php)

Comment: OP clearly asking for blender import, your link is to a plugin for 3dMax. Blender is a free software however 3dMax is not!